# Bootstrap Select Editable Combobox Hack

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, combobox, bootstrap-select

## How can I let my users add their own options to bootstrap-select?

Hello. After spending some time trying to find a simple solution that works with bootstrap 4 styling, including looking at the offered solutions and dead threads waiting on this open issue: https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/issues/990, I decided to roll my own.

The following solution relies on the live-search option to be enabled on the bootstrap-select element. It uses the live search field to add the user-typed, custom value to the list of options. It is a hacky solution and not the prettiest thing, but maybe this concept could be directly integrated into bootstrap select to finally solve issue 990.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Let the user add their own values to a bootstrap-select live-search capable selector

Just add this code to your page. Replace **(yourselector)** with your selector. For my project, I just wanted any selectpicker element that wasn't multiple capable, so I used *.selectpicker:not([multiple])*.

```js
var newOption;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Custom editable combobox
    $(document).on("loaded.bs.select", "(yourselector)", function (e, clickedIndex, isSelected, previousValue) {
        newOption = ""; //Reset newOption before doing a new search
        $(e.currentTarget).siblings(".dropdown-menu").on('keyup', '.bs-searchbox input', function (ie) {
            //if more than one and search is 0 characters, continue. If more than one and search is 1 character and character doesn't match first character of newValue, delete newValue.
            //If 1 and class is "no-results", delete old newValue and add newValue.
            console.log("running keyup script for " + e.currentTarget.id);

            var searchList = $(e.currentTarget).siblings("div.dropdown-menu ul.dropdown-menu li");
            var searchPhrase = $(ie.currentTarget).val();

            //Something was found
            if (searchList.length > 0 && !$(searchList[0]).hasClass("no-results")) {
                //new search
                if (searchPhrase.length == 0)
                    return;
                else {
                    //they haven't started searching the same phrase again
                    if (newOption && newOption.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchPhrase.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
                        console.log("newOption: " + newOption + "\nsearchPhrase: " + searchPhrase + "\nSubstring?: " + newOption.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchPhrase.toLowerCase()));
                        //delete newOption from options list and reset
                        $("#" + e.currentTarget.id + " option[value='" + newOption + "']").remove();
                        newOption = "";
                        $(e.currentTarget).selectpicker("refresh");
                        $(ie.currentTarget).trigger('propertychange');
                    }
                }
            }
            //Nothing was found
            else {
                $("#" + e.currentTarget.id + " option[value='" + newOption + "']").remove();
                newOption = searchPhrase;
                $(e.currentTarget).append($('<option>').val(searchPhrase).text(searchPhrase));
                $(e.currentTarget).selectpicker("refresh");
                $(ie.currentTarget).trigger('propertychange');
            }
        })
    });
    $(".selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select", function (e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
        newOption = ""; //Reset newOption before doing a new search
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Great script but your script keep empty ...

Just add after `$(e.currentTarget).append($('<option>').val(searchPhrase).text(searchPhrase));`

```
$(e.currentTarget).find("option").each(function(index, element) {
                        
                        if ( $(this).text() == "" )
                        {
                            $(this).remove();   
                        }
                    });
```